# Are there any examples of programming languages that didn't have recursive data types?

Tags: programming-languages

I'm interested in the history of programming languages. We take it for granted now that languages have some kind of `struct` type that can contain nested `struct`s within it (I believe this came from Algol68 and most modern languages followed suit). Are there any programming languages that lack a recursive `struct` type or something similar?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_data_type

I searched online and couldn't find questions like this but I may be missing the right terminology.

Comment: Some languages (e.g., forth) don't have any struct like data types.